# Postgresql (PLPGSQL) trigger assignment issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Given the following schema for a postgresql 9.5 database:

```
      --
      -- DOMAINS
      -- 
      CREATE DOMAIN data_sources_url_domain AS text NOT NULL;
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validates_format_of_url(url text) RETURNS bool AS $$
        BEGIN
          RETURN url ~* '^https?://';
        END;
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
      ALTER DOMAIN data_sources_url_domain ADD CONSTRAINT format_validation CHECK (validates_format_of_url(value));

      --
      -- TABLES
      --
      CREATE TABLE data_sources (
        id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1mc(),
        url data_sources_url_domain
      );

      --
      -- TRIGGERS & FUNCTIONS
      --
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION format_data_source_url() RETURNS trigger AS $format_data_source_url$
        DECLARE
          up_to_querystring text;
          querystring_to_end text;
          querystring_minus_fragment text;
        BEGIN
          up_to_querystring := split_part(NEW.url, '?', 1);

          IF length(up_to_querystring) = length(NEW.url) THEN
            NEW.url := lower(up_to_querystring);
            RETURN NEW;
          END IF;

          querystring_to_end := split_part(NEW.url, '?', 2);
          querystring_minus_fragment := split_part(querystring_to_end, '#', 1);

          NEW.url := lower(up_to_querystring) || '?' || querystring_minus_fragment;
          RETURN NEW;
        END;
      $format_data_source_url$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

      CREATE TRIGGER format_data_source_url BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON data_sources
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE format_data_source_url();
```

BOTH the following SQL statements:

```
INSERT INTO data_sources (url) VALUES ('HtTpS://www.example.com/things?foo=bar#fragment');
INSERT INTO data_sources (url) VALUES ('HtTpS://www.example.com/things');
```

Produce the following error:

> ERROR:  SPI_connect failed: SPI_ERROR_CONNECT
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function format_data_source_url() line `X` at assignment

With `line X` being either of the following lines:

```
10: NEW.url := lower(up_to_querystring);
17: NEW.url := lower(up_to_querystring) || '?' || querystring_minus_fragment;
```

Any ideas on what is causing this?

The only documentation I can really find about SPI is [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/historic-linux/distributions/redhat-5.0/i386/live/usr/doc/postgresql-6.2.1/doc/spi.txt), and it seems to be for triggers written in C; this trigger is in PL/PGSQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast to `data_sources_url_domain` before assigning to `NEW.url`.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION format_data_source_url() RETURNS trigger AS $format_data_source_url$
    DECLARE
      up_to_querystring text;
      querystring_to_end text;
      querystring_minus_fragment text;
    BEGIN
      up_to_querystring := split_part(NEW.url, '?', 1);

      IF length(up_to_querystring) = length(NEW.url) THEN
        NEW.url := lower(up_to_querystring)::data_sources_url_domain;
        RETURN NEW;
      END IF;

      querystring_to_end := split_part(NEW.url, '?', 2);
      querystring_minus_fragment := split_part(querystring_to_end, '#', 1);

      NEW.url := (lower(up_to_querystring) || '?' || querystring_minus_fragment)::data_sources_url_domain;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
  $format_data_source_url$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The error is weird though.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think, due to the inexact error, this is something that should be shared with the Postgresql Developers?

Comment: @ouroboros Yes, it looks like a bug to me. Postgresql 9.4 did not complain about it at all.